# How to implement direct message in Twitter API

Tags: php, twitter

How do I implement direct message in Twitter API?

A Direct Message is a private message sent via Twitter to one of your followers. (This is different than mentions and @replies.)

Could you show me a sample code on doing this. I believe that is uses PHP to do this.

Thanks in advance and Have a good day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not give the [Twitter Official API Docs on DM's](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api#direct-messages) a read? Try implementing it (you'll probably need to use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)) and let us know if you have any problems with your code.